# Sorting of mongodb based on oldest and max value record

Tags: mongodb-query

I want to write a query for sorting the mongodb collection in descending order based on the field value.This I have done as below:

```
    db.collection.find().sort("amount",-1)
```

But in this record the values in the `"amount"` parameter can be duplicate.eg., 
    the record can have the following values:

```
{ _id: 1, item: { category: "cake", type: "chiffon" }, amount: 10 }
{ _id: 2, item: { category: "cake", type: "chocolate chip" }, amount: 20 }
{ _id: 3, item: { category: "cookies", type: "lemon" }, amount: 30 }
{ _id: 4, item: { category: "cookies", type: "carrot" }, amount: 30 }
```

Now on sort in descending order, I will get the value as `30` on the topmost but it is in two records.
I want that among these two duplicate records, I should get oldest record($natural). So, how can I modify the above query based on this.

Comment: Please update your question with sample documents. The query you have tried. The result you obtained and the result you intend to get. That would help your question gain more attention. How would you determine which record is the oldest among those having the same value?

Comment: Actually I intend to get both. I need to set the records in descending order based on the "field". And if duplicate values are present for the topmost value, then I need to take the oldest record.

Comment: We can deteremine the oldest record using capped collection by using $natural. But If I am using both sceanrios in combination, then it is not working

Comment: modified by adding the actual records